# Extracting regions in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph

Suppose now I have an image segmentation map S, whose indices range in 1 to k. Indices with same numbers belongs to the same segment. For example:

```
S = [1 1 1 2 2 2;
     1 1 1 2 2 2;
     2 2 2 2 1 1;
     2 2 2 2 1 1;
     2 2 2 2 1 1]
```

For this segmentation map S, I would like to get regions. For example, the '1' in S has two isolated parts, so I would like to get three regions--two with label 1 and one with label 2, and to distinguish two '1's, I would like to change one of it to be another label, say 3. So the final map is:

```
S = [1 1 1 2 2 2;
     1 1 1 2 2 2;
     2 2 2 2 3 3;
     2 2 2 2 3 3;
     2 2 2 2 3 3]
```

I'm thinking of using connected component to solve this problem, but it requires to formulate the affinity matrix. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not using bwconncomp or bwlabel? It is particularly suited to this problem

Comment: So you want to obtain the second `S` matrix?

Comment: @EitanT Yes. And now the problem is solved. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get a logical matrix of all ones and then get all connected elements with `bwlabel`. You can them merge them together. To avoid problems of mixing two areas, just add the max of the original matrix For example:

```
mask           = (S == 1);
labeled        = bwlabel (mask);
labeled(mask)  = labeled(mask) + max (S(:)) - 1;
labeled         = S + labeled;
```

The only difference is that none of the regions that before had a value of "1" have that value now, but at least they are labeled different. If you want one of them to keep their number, it's just a matter of making another mask for the highest value, and use it to turn all them back to "1".

```
labeled(S == max(S(:))) = 1;
```